# Probability with discrete variable

Tags: probability

> A factory makes a large number of face-masks. The probability that a mask is substandard is $0.02$. Compute or approximate the probability that a sample of $400$ masks will contain $4$ or more substandard ones.

I used a variable $X$ -"number of masks being substandard"
can i compute it this way:
$P(X\geq4)=(1-p)^{4-1}$? Or should I use another formula/approach?

Comment: yes exactly this

Comment: I'd suggest trying with $P(X\geq 4) = 1 - P(X<4)$. Do you know how to find $P(X=0)$, $P(X=1)$, ..., $P(X=3)$?

Comment: p(x=k)=(1-p)^(k-1)*p?

Comment: Have a look at the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: do you suggest to find p(X=0) P(X=1 ),....P(X=3) and then minus them from 1?

Comment: Think about why this is true in this particular exercise $P(X<4)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)$.

Comment: because these are independent ivents and adding their probability will give their union?

Comment: Because they are [mutually exclusive](https://brilliant.org/wiki/probability-rule-of-sum/). You have all the ingredients to finish this exercise now.

Comment: @Silvija The events X=0, X=1, X=2, X=3 are disjoint (not independent) events, so the probabilities add.

Comment: I am just curious why i do not use the information of the fact that its the sample 400 masks and just calculate the probability

Comment: @Silvija you will use that information to calculate $P(X=0)$ to $P(X=3)$ using [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), I mentioned that earlier.